# Updating text or html for label doesn't work and throws no errors

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have some code that dynamically assigns an ID to an HTML element.

I've written additional code to use this ID attribute to change the text as the user selects different options from a SELECT Box.

Here's the HTML:

```
<DT>Contact Type</DT>
<DD>
<select name="contact_types"  id="contact_types" ><option  selected value="" ></option></select>
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT>change me dynamically</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
```

Here's the code to find the label in question as soon as the document loads, and assign an ID:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        //find element that has generic text and assign an id.
        $('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
            var exp = /change me dynamically/;

            if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {

                var $parent = $(this).parent().attr('id', 'contactTypeLabel');
                $parent.text(function(_, text){
                   return  text.replace(exp, "Phone Number");
                }); 

            }
        });
```

And here's the code that attempts to change the text of label thats just been assigned an id:

```
        $("#contact_types").live("change",function()  {         
            var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").html();           
            selectedtext = selectedtext.toUpperCase();
            alert(selectedtext);
            switch(selectedtext)
            {
                    case 'EMAIL':
                        $('#contactTypeLabel').text("eMail Address:");
                        break;
                    case 'MOBILE PHONE':
                        $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Phone Number:");
                        break;
                    case 'VOICE MAIL':
                        $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Number / Extension:");
                        break;      
            }
        });
 });
```

When I test out this logic, the label doesn't change as I'm selecting different options from the drop down box. 
But i don't get any errors either in the console....
I've tried using both IE and Firefox. 
I've also tried using the .html method instead of the .text for the label.  But that didn't work either.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

When I type:

```
$('#contactTypeLabel')
```

into the console, i get the following text:

```
>> $('#contactTypeLabel'); 
{
    0 : [object HTMLScriptElement],
    length : 1,
    context : [object Document],
    selector : "#contactTypeLabel",
    constructor : function(a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)},
    init : function(a,e,f){var g,i,j,k;if(!a)return this;if(a.nodeType){this.context=this[0]=a,this.length=1;return this}if(a==="body"&&!e&&c.body){this.context=c,this[0]=c.body,this.selector="body",this.length=1;return this}if(typeof a==="string"){g=h.exec(a);if(!,
    jquery : "1.5.2",
    size : function(){return this.length},
    toArray : function(){return C.call(this,0)},
    get : function(a){return a==null?this.toArray():a<0?this[this.length+a]:this[a]}
    ...
} 
Add to watch
```

**EDIT 2**

As as a test, I changed the jquery that assigns the ID to look like this:

```
    //find element that has generic text and assign an id.
        $('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
            var exp = /change me dynamically/;

            if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {

                var $parent = $(this).parent().attr('id', 'contactTypeLabel');
                 $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Number / Extension:");
            }
        });
```

And sure enough, it's not working... 
So maybe the ID is not being assigned correctly??

**EDIT 3**

The drop down list is being populated by an ajax call  like so:

```
$.getJSON(
url = myurl,
function(data)    {

            sessionStorage.setItem("voicecontacttypes", data); //save as string data.
    data = $.parseJSON(data); 
        if (data !=null) {
            $.each(data, function(i) {
                  $('#contact_types')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",this.id)      

                                .text(this.description));
        }); //end .each                             
    }//end if
    }//end data
);//end getJSON
```

Comment: What do you get if you type $('#contactTypeLabel'); in the console?  Does it work if you type $('#contactTypeLabel').text('changed'); in the console?

Comment: what version of jQuery are u using?

Comment: jquery version 1.5.2.  Brian, check out my edit re: results from console command

Comment: David, I've changed my original post to include the HTML in question.

Comment: ID is assigned - I've tested this.

Comment: Can you please add the true html (ie generated on the page, not your coded HTML) you have no select options.

Comment: abc123, the html you see is the true html. I just ahve another jquery function that does ajax call to get data to populate lists... I will add that code for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me.  I think it is because you are using `.html` instead of `.text` for the `select`.

IE: `var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").text();` instead of `var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").html();`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/jSfgn/3/

JS:

Change:

```
//find element that has generic text and assign an id.
    $('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
        var exp = /change me dynamically/;

        if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {

            var $parent = $(this).parent().attr('id', 'contactTypeLabel');
            $parent.text(function(_, text){
               return  text.replace(exp, "Phone Number");
            }); 

        }
    });
```

TO:

```
//find element that has generic text and assign an id.
    $('body > DT :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
        var exp = /change me dynamically/;

        if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {

            var $parent = $(this).parent().attr('id', 'contactTypeLabel');
            $parent.text(function(_, text){
               return  text.replace(exp, "Phone Number");
            }); 

        }
    });
```

JS:

Change:

```
   $("#contact_types").live("change",function()  {         
        var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").html();           
        selectedtext = selectedtext.toUpperCase();
        alert(selectedtext);
        switch(selectedtext)
        {
                case 'EMAIL':
                    $('#contactTypeLabel').text("eMail Address:");
                    break;
                case 'MOBILE PHONE':
                    $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Phone Number:");
                    break;
                case 'VOICE MAIL':
                    $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Number / Extension:");
                    break;      
        }
    });
 });
```

TO:

```
$("#contact_types").live("change", function () {
    var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").text();
    selectedtext = selectedtext.toUpperCase();
    alert(selectedtext);
    switch (selectedtext) {
        case 'EMAIL':
            $('#contactTypeLabel').text("eMail Address:");
            break;
        case 'MOBILE PHONE':
            $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Phone Number:");
            break;
        case 'VOICE MAIL':
            $('#contactTypeLabel').text("Number / Extension:");
            break;
    }
});
```

Please change your JS to do Ajax to the following:

```
$.getJSON(url = myurl, function (data) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("voicecontacttypes", data); //save as string data.
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    if (data != null) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data, function (i) {                
                html = html + "<option value=\"" + this.id + "\">" + this.description + "</option>";
        }); //end .each                             
        $('#contact_types').html(html);
    } //end if
} //end data
); //end getJSON
```

**Reason**: this makes your tightly nested for loop only access the DOM 1 time instead of 1 time for each value returned which will slow a lot of browsers down, and if there are over 1000 options it can crash IE.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  Well, I know it isn't cuz I tried it and it doesn't work. =/  Thanks though for trying.  The values are not the same as the HTML text.  In my case, I want to check the HTML, not val.

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle?  It certainly seems to work.  If you want to use the text just change var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").val(); to var selectedtext = $("#contact_types option:selected").text();

Comment: DoctorMick, I think the issue is with the logic that sets the ID... check out EDIT 2

Comment: abc123, my html doesn't look like yours at all.  You'll notice that I don't have an element that has the correct ID to start with.  i'm trying to do that dynamically.

Comment: i'll re-update my answer now that you've included the html.  As a sidenote you can have a span with an id and no text it won't show anything, then you can just set it's value.

Comment: abc123, if i could change the html, I would actually be using divs... but i have no control over the html that's generated initially

Comment: I understand that you can't change the HTML but i just want the final generated html so i can do the code for you.  Or show the backend code that is doing the generation

Comment: That's whats included in the post... the is the final html... and then just whatever jquery code to manipulate it.  hope that clarifies.  what's your opinion on comments in Elmo's answer..?

Comment: abc123, I've added another EDIT to my post to show you the jquery to populate my <SELECT>.  HOpe that helps.

Comment: @markli updated my code once again to help you, please note that i changed the ajax code to make it faster and less troublesome in the future.  I promise that this will work for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32704/discussion-between-mark-li-and-abc123)

Comment: I see the problem is solved - could you tell us what happened?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo it appears to me that the primary problem was $('body :contains("change me dynamically")') it was finding this twice and thereby setting two things to having an ID of contactTypeLabel, which made for a problem.  Other than that markli would have to explain

Answer (score 2):

From the console output, I see that you have selected `HTMLScriptElement` not the `HTMLLabelElement`. Apparently, you have set `id` for script element of your HTML.

Comment: Elmo, that's interesting.  But if that's the case, would the logic that initially changes the text from "change me dynamically" to "Phone Number" work?  That part of the code is working...

Comment: In the first code sample, you are setting the attribute `id` for the label and changing text to "Phone Number". My concern is that there is a script tag somewhere in HTML with the same `id` and selector ` $('#contactTypeLabel')` selects only this `script` tag.

Comment: Elmo, after lunch I will do a view source on the page and search for "contactTypeLabel" and see if it comes up with anything...

Comment: Elmo, I've searched the rendered page for "change me dynamically". 3  matches are found.  Match 1:  $('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
 Match 2:  var exp = /change me dynamically/; and finally, Match 3: <DT>change me dynamically</DT>

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works.

What I'm thinking the is: if you have any spaces, linefeeds, etc, in the html of the options it won't match anything in your select statement. What I would suggest is using selectedtext = $.trim(selected text.toUpperCase());

That should fix it (hopefully!)

Comment: hm... I tried that Chelsea... but didn't resolve it. Are you using my code from original post or from Edits?

Comment: I'm using your current code. What is your alert outputting? There's no html tags or anything in there is there?

Comment: my alert shows the correct text - representing the value that is currently selected in the drop down...